# convert Map<Object, Object> to JSONObject

Tags: java

I am trying to convert map to JSONObject. but receiving java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String

```
Map<Object, Object> mapObj = new HashMap<Object, Object>();     
Object test = new Object();

mapObj.put("key_string", "test_String");
mapObj.put(test, new Object());

JSONObject actualObj = (JSONObject) convertMap(mapObj);

private Object convertMap(Object value) {        
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject((Map<?, ?>) value); // here error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    return jsonObj;
}
```

Comment: What JSON would you expect this code to produce?

Comment: i just want to store map into jsonobject.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: JB Nizet , i am not sure. i guess this format {"key_string":"test_string", "Object_in-string":"obj-value"}; or can u suggest some JSOn format as i am new.

Comment: An Object doesn't have any value. And its toString() representation is something like java.lang.Object@4563538. What would you do with that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: JB Nizet thats ok for me. i am worried why JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject((Map<?, ?>) value); is giving ClassCastException error. can we solve by some way?

Comment: JSON object keys are strings. An Object is not a String. That's why you get an exception. You have still not told what you wanted to achieve. What's the point in generating JSON containing unusable keys and values?

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: thank you for the answer. closed